# undefined method `multi' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq, puma

I use dokku, puma, sidekiq and sidkiq-status
Sometimes I have this error:
Error message

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `multi' for nil:NilClass

    Sample stack trace (show Rails)
    …ems/sidekiq-status-0.5.4/lib/sidekiq-status/
    storage.rb:  16:in `block in store_for_id'
    …ems/sidekiq-status-0.5.4/lib/sidekiq-status/
    storage.rb: 103:in `block in redis_connection'
    ….2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/
    connection_pool.rb:  64:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    ….2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/
    connection_pool.rb:  63:in `handle_interrupt'
    ….2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/
    connection_pool.rb:  63:in `block in with'
    ….2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/
    connection_pool.rb:  60:in `handle_interrupt'
    ….2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/
    connection_pool.rb:  60:in `with'
    …ems/sidekiq-status-0.5.4/lib/sidekiq-status/
    storage.rb: 102:in `redis_connection'
    …ems/sidekiq-status-0.5.4/lib/sidekiq-status/
    storage.rb:  15:in `store_for_id'
    …ems/sidekiq-status-0.5.4/lib/sidekiq-status/
    storage.rb:  32:in `store_status'
    …q-status-0.5.4/lib/sidekiq-status/
    client_middleware.rb:  11:in `call'
    …2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.5.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/
    chain.rb: 129:in `block in invoke'
    …2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.5.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/
    chain.rb: 132:in `call'
    …2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.5.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/
    chain.rb: 132:in `invoke'
    …le/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.5.4/lib/sidekiq/
    client.rb: 208:in `process_single'
    …le/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.5.4/lib/sidekiq/
    client.rb:  65:in `push'
    …le/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.5.4/lib/sidekiq/
    worker.rb:  98:in `client_push'
    …le/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.5.4/lib/sidekiq/
    worker.rb:  54:in `perform_async'
    /app/app/controllers/reports/
    report_items_controller.rb:  90:in `params_to_session'
    …0/gems/actionview-4.2.5.1/lib/action_view/
    rendering.rb:  30:in `process'
```

Sidekiq lost redis connection...
My Sidekiq.rb

```
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/web'
require 'sidekiq-cron'
require 'sidekiq-status'

Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { backtrace: true, retry: false }

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|

  config.redis = { url: App.redis, size: 20 }

  if ENV['DATABASE_URL'].present?
    database_url = "#{ENV['DATABASE_URL']}?pool=25"
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(database_url)
  else
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ServerMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes # default
  end

  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware
  end
  Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'sidekiq_cron.yml'))

end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: App.redis, size: 2 }
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware
  end
end
```

My puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['PUMA_WORKERS'] || 2)
threads Integer(ENV['MIN_THREADS']  || 1), Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 32)

preload_app!

rackup DefaultRackup
port ENV['PORT'] || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

prune_bundler

on_worker_boot do
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    end
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
  end

  if defined?(REDIS)
    uri = URI.parse(App.redis)
    REDIS = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
  end

  sidekiq_redis = { :url => ENV["REDIS_URL"] }
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = sidekiq_redis
  end
  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
     config.redis = sidekiq_redis
  end
end
```

How can I solve this problem?